# Passing img element as return value

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-8

I have html5 WP8 app under development.
In html/js side I collect some data (text and images) which I'm supposed to send over to c# to be emailed forward.
I have function in javascript

```
function toEmail() {
var dataToSend = getNextEntry();
return dataToSend;
}
```

And I call it from from c# with

```
string toBeEmailed;
toBeEmailed = (string)Browser.invokeScript("toEmail");
```

And this works fine. But now I should do the same with image stored in img.src. How can I do that? What datatype should I cast the return value etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use can get image as base64 string.

For example:

```
function img2base64(img)
{
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

    return canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"));
}
```